# Integrate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(\frac{1+ix}{1-ix})}{e^{2\pi x} - 1} dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

How to calculate the following integral :

$$\int_0^ \infty \frac {\log (\frac{1+ix}{1-ix})}{e^{2πx}-1} dx$$

Where, i is the unit imaginary number or iota .

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: First, take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms, then let $a=2\pi$ in this duplicate: [How to evaluate improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{-1}{x}}{e^{ax}-1}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831304/how-to-evaluate-improper-integral-int-0-infty-frac-tan-1xeax-1)

Comment: @Zacky thank you

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html