# On an application of the Abel-Plana formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, euler-maclaurin

Referring to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818609/help-with-a-troublesome-double-integral), i am having a hard time trying to do the integral:

> $$f(s)=-i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log \left[1+\frac{\left(s\log(1+ix) \right )^{2}}{4\pi ^{2}} \right ]-\log \left[1+\frac{\left(s\log(1-ix) \right )^{2}}{4\pi ^{2}} \right ]}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx$$

$s$ being a complex parameter. I have tried to apply the Abel-Plana formula. Namely,
we have:
$$\int\log\left(1+\frac{(s\log(1+x))^{2}}{4\pi^{2}} \right ) dx=(1+x)\log\left(1+\frac{(s\log(1+x))^{2}}{4\pi^{2}} \right ) $$
$$-e^{2\pi i /s}\text{Ei}\left(\log(1+x)-\frac{2\pi i }{s} \right )-e^{-2\pi i /s}\text{Ei}\left(\log(1+x)+\frac{2\pi i }{s} \right )$$
Where $\text{Ei}\left(\cdot\right)$ is the exponential integral function. Thus, by direct application of the Able-Plana formula :
$$f(s)=e^{2\pi i /s}\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{2\pi i }{s} \right )+e^{-2\pi i /s}\text{Ei}\left(\frac{2\pi i }{s} \right ) $$

$$+\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+N\right)\log\left(1+\frac{\left(s\log(1+N)\right)^{2}}{4\pi^{2}}\right)$$
$$-e^{2\pi i /s}\text{Ei}\left(\log(1+N)-\frac{2\pi i }{s} \right )-e^{-2\pi i /s}\text{Ei}\left(\log(1+N)+\frac{2\pi i }{s} \right )$$
$$-\sum_{n=0}^{N}\log\left(1+\frac{(s\log(1+n))^{2}}{4\pi^{2}} \right ) $$
However, i haven't been able to obtain a meaningful result of the limit yet.

EDIT:
Using the asymptotic estimate of the exponential integral function, the limit reduces to:
$$\lim _{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\log\left(1+\frac{(s\log N)^{2}}{4\pi^{2}} \right )-\log\left(1+\frac{(s\log n)^{2}}{4\pi^{2}} \right )\right]-N\left(\frac{2\log N}{(\log N)^{2}+\frac{4\pi^{2}}{s^{2}}} \right )$$
Or :

$$2\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left[\int_{\log n}^{\log N}\frac{x}{x^{2}+\frac{4\pi^{2}}{s^{2}}}dx-\left(\frac{\log N}{(\log N)^{2}+\frac{4\pi^{2}}{s^{2}}} \right ) \right ]$$

Comment: I don't think Abel-Plana is useful here as the integral you would need to evaluate that way diverges.

Comment: true ... but i suspect that a certain limiting process could cancel the divergence. namely, the divergence of integral gets absorbed by that of the summation.

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal In that case, you must check the asymptotic expansions of ${\rm Ei}$.

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal I must say, I really admire your tanacity with regards to solving this problem. :)